# A bound for the radius of a convex set of diameter $d$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

Given $C$ the convex hull of the points $Y_1,\ldots,Y_K$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Call $d$, the diameter of $C$. Suppose without loss of generality that $\|Y_1-Y_2\|=d$. Take $Y_0=(Y_1+Y_2)/2$. I need an upper bound for $\max\limits_{c\in C}\|c-Y_0\|$ in terms of $d$.

I thought the problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and got that $\max\limits_{c\in C}\|c-Y_0\|\le\sqrt{3}d/{2}$. I'm not quite sure, I thought that the points $Y_j$ necessarily live in the intersection of the balls $B(Y_1,d)$ and $B(Y_2,d)$ and the greatest possible distance to $Y_0$ is achieved in the points belonging to the intersections of the respective circles and this is by Pythagoras $\sqrt{3}d/2$. I believe the same bound might work for higher dimenssions.

Thank you for helping

Comment: The argument and the calculated values sound OK also for higher dimensions and are sharp. Note that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem gives a better bound if you can also choose the 'center' of your $\max$ more freely instead of being limited to $Y_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I believe that the link you sent me may be very usefull to me if I could calculate the ``center'' of the convex hull which achieves the bound of the theorem in terms of the points $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$. Per happs do you know if there is a concrete way of calculate it or to approximate it? Tank you again.

Comment: I'm sorry, you might have to search for that yourself, I just rememered it from long ago for the 2-dimensional case.